# cp -r from_dir/* to_dir with python

Tags: python, directory, shutil

Is there an easy way to emulate the command `cp -r from_dir/* to_dir` with python? `shutil.copytree` is not suitable because `to_dir` exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the source code of `shutil.copytree`, adapt it and use:

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    """Recursively copy a directory tree using copy2().

    The destination directory must not already exist.
    If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.

    If the optional symlinks flag is true, symbolic links in the
    source tree result in symbolic links in the destination tree; if
    it is false, the contents of the files pointed to by symbolic
    links are copied.

    The optional ignore argument is a callable. If given, it
    is called with the `src` parameter, which is the directory
    being visited by copytree(), and `names` which is the list of
    `src` contents, as returned by os.listdir():

        callable(src, names) -> ignored_names

    Since copytree() is called recursively, the callable will be
    called once for each directory that is copied. It returns a
    list of names relative to the `src` directory that should
    not be copied.

    XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.

    """
    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    os.makedirs(dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                copy2(srcname, dstname)
            # XXX What about devices, sockets etc.?
        except (IOError, os.error), why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except Error, err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
    try:
        copystat(src, dst)
    except OSError, why:
        if WindowsError is not None and isinstance(why, WindowsError):
            # Copying file access times may fail on Windows
            pass
        else:
            errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise Error, errors
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to `copytree` with the correct name (or same name)

```
shutil.copytree("/path/from_dir","/destination/from_dir")
```

Comment: it's not the same, I want to copy the content of the directory, not the directory

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["cp", "-rt", "to_dir"] + glob.glob("from_dir/*"))
```

Sometimes it's nice to do everything directly in Python yourself; then again, it's often nicer to just call the command that you know how to control and know works.

I'd not hesitate to rewrite this <s>if</s> when requirements change, but until then, it's short and readable — more time is better spent on bigger problems.  A good example of how they might change is reporting an error: you've not said anything about that, but I wouldn't be parsing cp's output once that's required.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that `cp` could generate output, which you may not want. Consider sending stdout/stderr to `/dev/null`.

Comment: this is very similar to what I'm doing now, but it's not portable

Comment: @wiso: Could you update the question with your target platforms/environments?

Comment: @roger: platform/environments indipendent